# UICollectionViewCell autolayout installed views not working

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

When creating a view inside a UICollectionViewCell that should only show for a specific size class, this view is always visible on initial launch no matter what the size class.

i.e if the view should only be shown for compact width loading the app with iPhone (regular width) will also show the view until rotated.

The constraints are set as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an XCode bug with how it views the auto layout constraints. The work around is to be extra verbose with the constraints and untick the default 'installed' check box.

The constraints are now

[image]

I have filed a radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5056687413133312